# How to share wifi connection on laptop to mobile phone with no cellular network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb, android

**Scenario**

I have a mobile phone and a laptop. I'd like to share the laptop internet connection to the mobile phone.

The laptop can connect to internet (wifi interface available to access internet), operating system windows 7.

The mobile phone has no cellular network available (there is no signal). This device is not allowed to connect to the wifi network by which the laptop access the internet. Operating system is android 5.

**Question**

There is a way to share internet connection on laptop to mobile phone? I mean, apart using a ethernet-to-wifi adapter.

**What i have tried so far**

I have tried plugging usb cable, but the phone is recognized as media device or storage device. By phone side, in "usb options" is not listed an option about network interface. By laptop side, in the "share connection configuration" menu there is no way to select usb interface as network interface.

Thank you

Comment: Also see: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171049/209414

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do what you need is to use WiFi.

You have to create Hosted Network (Hotspot) on your laptop and then your cell connects to this WiFi network. In this case it will use your laptop as router and can access to the internet.

[Here is description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168152/use-netsh-wlan-set-hostednetwork-to-create-a-wifi-hotspot-and-the-authenti) how to create WiFi Hosted Network on your laptop using netsh command.

Comment: Thank you. Just a clarification: the laptop wifi interface will provide internet connection to the laptop, and at the same time act as a hotspot for the cell?

Comment: Yes, it should.